Scaling the objective function in a constrained optimization problem
I am trying to minimize a scalar function $f(\bf x)$ while satisfying a vector of constraints ${\bf {c}}({\bf{x}})$. Together, the function and the constraints form the Lagrangian
$$
L({\bf x}, {\bf \lambda}) = f({\bf x}) + {\bf c}({{\bf{x}}})^T {\bf \lambda}
$$
Where ${\bf \lambda}$ is a vector of Lagrange multipliers, and the derivatives of the Laplacian are given as
$$
\nabla_{\bf x} L({\bf x}, {\bf \lambda}) = {\bf g} + {\bf A}^T {\bf \lambda}
$$
and
$$
\nabla_{\bf \lambda} L({\bf x}, {\bf \lambda}) = {\bf c}({\bf x})
$$
Where $\bf A$ is the Jacobian of constraints and $g = \nabla f({\bf x})$.
Because both sets of derivatives are zero when $L({\bf x}, {\bf \lambda})$ is minimized, the derivatives are used as termination conditions in some optimization algorithms, e.g. Byrd-Omojokun (trust region) algorithms.
Typically, ${\bf \lambda}$ is solved by the normal equation
$$
{\bf A}{\bf A}^T {\bf \lambda} = -{\bf A}{\bf g} 
$$
In the problem that I am solving $f({\bf x})$, and therefore $g({\bf x})$, have very large-values. I have observed as a result that ${\bf \lambda}$ too has large values which makes the first of the two sets of termination conditions, $\nabla_{\bf x} L({\bf x}, {\bf \lambda})$ large at every iteration so that and the solver does not terminate, even though $\nabla_{\bf \lambda} L({\bf x}, {\bf \lambda}) \approx 0$. And when the solver does finally terminate because the number of iterations has been exceeded I find that the last iterates $\bf x$ are acceptable solutions. Which suggests that the termination conditions did not pass even though a solution had been found.
So now I am thinking of scaling $f({\bf x})$ down, as this should not affect the solution of the minimization problem but I'd like to know the following:

How commonplace is it for solvers to do this?
Are there any principled ways of doing this? How should a scaling factor be chosen. Surely there is such a thing as too much or too little scaling.

Update
I think I now understand why the Lagrangian gradient $\nabla L_{\bf x}$ is not converging in my case. The problem is that $c({\bf x})$ and thus ${\bf A}({\bf x})$ are sparse whereas $g({\bf x})$ is dense. As such there is no $\lambda$ that can make $\nabla L_{\bf x} \approx 0$. Is it okay to only consider the components of
$\nabla L_{\bf x}$ that can be "zeroed" by $\lambda$ as the termination condition?

I think if you could say more about the physical problem you're trying to solve, then suggesting different scaling schemes would be easier.

The problem is from elasticity. The function is the total strain energy of a deformed body.

Standard ways to address this problem: I) scale the gradients of f and c based on their magnitude at the initial point (a la IPOPT); ii) scale the stationarity residual with the norm of the multipliers (a la filterSQP).

So are you using the $2$-norm of $\nabla L$ as stopping criterion? If this is so then switch to a relative error, although for ill-conditioned problems you may have issues even then. Also have you tried using the relative residual, or the relative residual rescaled by the psueodinverse of the Jacobian as stopping criterion?

@CharlieVanaret (i) Surely approach is sensitive to start conditions. My start point is the "rest state", where $f = 0$. (2) Is equation 6 (from the filterSQP manual) the "norm of the multiplier" that you are referring to?

@lightxbulb Not the 2-Norm but the "infnorm", i.e. the largest element of the vector $\nabla_\lambda$.
How would the "relative error" and "relative residual" be calculated?

Relative error is what Charlie Vanaret suggested - you require a decrease of the gradient: $$|\nabla L(x^k)| \leq \epsilon |\nabla L(x^0)|$$
Yes, it depends on the initial guess, but you could pick $\epsilon$ accordingly. E.g. in standard linear solvers like CG people often figure out the $\epsilon$ based on arguments about the conditioning of the problem and trial and error. Your multipliers account only for how well the constraints are satisfied, they don't tell you how well you minimized $f$. Regarding the residual, I made an assumption that is likely incorrect based on your cmnt $f=0$

@Olumide: yes, Eq. 6 in the filterSQP manual.

I wonder why this scaling is sometimes necessary. Could it be due to imprecision in large floating point values?

It's both due to floating point error and the conditioning of the problem. But probably a much more important argument is efficiency - in practice you need your results only up to some precision, so solving to machine precision is often overkill and a waste of computational resources and time. There are in fact cases where solving some step of an algorithm to a high precision is in fact detrimental (e.g. nonlinear problems with Newton and inexact Jacobian system solves).

Have you considered regularizing the objective to eliminate the non uniqueness in some components of x?
